# Why does the live view switch off for a long time and my photo is of low quality when I take a picture in low light?

Tags: nikon, aperture, iso, nikon-d3200

I have Nikon D3200. I am trying to take picture in A mode. I have set Aperture f/3 and ISO to 200. I am taking a picture in very low light.

The problem I am facing is that when I press the shutter button, the camera Live view turns off, and I have to turn off the camera and on it again, or I have to wait very long to view the image, and when I view the image its all messed up, and if I take a picture in pre-defined modes, for example 'Sports' Mode, it works fine.

Kindly tell me why its not working properly in A mode or and other Manual Mode.

Thanks,
Aftab

Answer (score 4):

When you are taking a picture at low ISO in the dark, even with a relatively wide aperture (f/3? Are you sure? That's an odd number not normally used in the sequence), the shutter speed is going to be very long — possibly several seconds.
The sport mode probably cranks the ISO way up to prevent this.

So, that's one thing. And you are probably not using a tripod, so it's going to be impossible to get a sharp image, because you just can't hold the camera still for more than a small fraction of second, even if you have very steady hands.

Then, the next thing that happens is that the camera is automatically enabling **dark frame subtraction**. This helps cancel out noise by taking a *second* exposure of the same length but with the shutter closed, and then canceling out anything that appears (because it must just be noise from the sensor, not light from the actual scene). That's why your camera isn't responsive immediately.

On the D3200, this happens automatically when your shutter speed is **1 second or longer**. See page 131 [in the manual](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D3200_EN.pdf); the exact conditions vary based on sensor temperature (hotter is worse) and it kicks in sooner at high ISO (but low ISO may require a longer shutter speed, so it will kick in anyway). You will see `Job nr`, for "Job noise reduction" in the viewfinder while this happens.

On some cameras, you can disable this. On the D3200, you can set NR to "Off", but this really means "less", not *actually* off, and I'm not sure offhand if this disables dark-frame subtraction. Unless you are manually taking a dark frame and using it in your RAW conversion software, you probably actually want it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a picture in low light at ISO 200, the shutter speed may be very slow.  If the camera moves at all during the exposure, the image is going to be a jumbled mess.  The camera is actually capturing data the entire time that the shutter is open and it is entirely possible that it could take 10 or more seconds to get an exposure (most DSLRs will go up to 30 seconds or so without having to use a bulb exposure mode to keep it open longer).

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that, when trying to take a picture with f/3 and ISO 200, the calculated exposure time is > 1 second. If you see this happen in manual mode ("M"), try to have a look at the shutter speed.

Sports mode is designed for action shots, so it by default tends to select shorter exposure times at the expense of ISO and aperture.

You might either to produce more light at the scene, or increase your ISO sensitivity if you can't (or don't want to) open the aperture any further.